# Disallow NULL parameters to stored procedures in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, stored-functions

I can specify that table columns are NOT NULL, but how do I make a stored procedure or function only be compatible with non-null arguments? Adding NOT NULL after the argument name doesn't work.

Comment: @peterm You are totally right, I missed that and removed my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to validate passed parameter values yourself. If you're using MySQL 5.5 and up you can make use of [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure (IN param1 INT)
BEGIN
  IF param1 IS NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NULL is not allowed.';
  END IF;
  -- do whatever 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d797d/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad there's no more efficient way to do it, given this adds a lot of cruft to the code when you have to do it for all non-null parameters.